# Using Munki to push iOS update to iPods

Tags: ios

I am in a new IT position as IT Manager Assistant and we are limited in our experience with Munki, we are managing a new call center that uses iMacs and iPods as tools at each work station. We have are trying to figure out how to  push the iOS 9 update to 270 iPods at the same time. Any help in finding assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To manage large numbers of iOS devices, you will need to use a MDM (Mobile Device Management).  More information from Apple can be found at  https://www.apple.com/support/business-education/mdm/ .

There are several third party MDM solutions. A few examples are...
Airwatch - http://www.air-watch.com/
JAMF Software - http://www.jamfsoftware.com/products/casper-suite/
Filewave - https://www.filewave.com/products/manage/mobile-device-management

Currently munki does not manage iOS devices.